# Why can I not solve this simple simultaneous equation?

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations, divisibility

$$\frac{B}{A}=\frac{C}{2B}=\frac{A}{4C}$$

Obviously, I assume $A \neq 0, B \neq 0, C \neq 0$.

From the above expression I chose three equations:

$$\frac{B}{A} = \frac{C}{2B}$$
$$\frac{C}{2B} = \frac{A}{4C}$$
$$\frac{B}{A}= \frac{A}{4C}$$

but cannot go further; if I solve them, it leads to an absurd identity (like $2B^2 = 2B^2$, for example) not a useful result.

But why?

Comment: I would start like so:
$$
\frac{B}{A} = \frac{C}{2B} = \frac{A}{4C} = t
$$
Now multiply the equations by the denominator, and you get
$$
B=At \qquad C = 2Bt \qquad A = 4Ct
$$
Take the last equation and plug in the middle one ... Can you continue from here?

Comment: @MattiP. Thanks a bunch. So as player3236 in the answer section mentioned we can only evaluate the ratio between the quantities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this looks like three equations in three unknowns, in fact there are only two equations. The third one is just a restatement of the other two. This means that you're not going to be able to find independent values for all three unknowns. Given that fact, decide on which two equations you're going to concentrate (it doesn't matter) and decide which variable you are going to keep as an unknown - then find the other two variables in terms of that variable.

Suppose you choose

$$\frac{B}{A} = \frac{C}{2B}$$
$$\frac{C}{2B} = \frac{A}{4C}$$

and decide to make $A$ your unknown.

Then your equations become

${2B^2}={AC}$ and $2C^2=AB$

Squaring the first gives $4B^4=A^2C^2$

Multiply by 2 gives $8B^4=2A^2C^2$

But we know that $2C^2=AB$ so $8B^4=A^2 \times AB$

$8B^3=A^3$

$B=\frac 12 A$

$\frac {\frac 12 A}{A}=\frac{C}{A}$

$C=\frac 12 A$

Comment: Ah, so that for $n$ equalities it matches with the fact that there are to be $n$ number of effective equations? Like for $n=2$, the case I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

From the equation $\dfrac BA = \dfrac C{2B} = \dfrac A{4C}$, we see that these are only the ratios between $A, B$ and $C$. There is no way to find their exact values. For example, if each of $A,B$ and $C$ are doubled, the equation still holds.

However we can still find the exact ratios between them. Observe that:

$$\left(\frac BA\right)^3 = \frac BA \cdot \frac C{2B} \cdot \frac {A}{4C}= \frac18$$

Hence we have $\dfrac BA = \dfrac12 = \dfrac C{2B} = \dfrac A{4C}$. This shows that $A:B:C = 2:1:1$.